# Efficiently find the dot product of two lists of vectors stored as PyTorch tensors & preserve backprop

Tags: python, pytorch

Suppose I had tensors `X` and `Y` which are both `(batch_size, d)` dimensional. I would like to find the `(batch_size x 1)` tensor resulting from `[X[0]@Y[0].T, X[1]@Y[1].T, ...]`

There are two ways I can think of doing this, neither of which are particularly efficient.

#### Way 1

```
product = torch.eye(batch_size) * X@Y.T
product = torch.sum(product, dim=1)
```

This works, but for large matrices there are a LOT of wasted computations

#### Way 2

```
product = torch.cat(
    [ X[i]@Y[i].T for i in X.size(0) ],
    dim=0
)
```

This is good in that no cycles are wasted, but it won't leverage any of the built-in parallelism torch offers.

I'm aware that numpy has a method that will do this, but converting the tensors to np arrays will destroy the chain of backpropagation, and this is for a neural net, so that's not an option.

Am I missing an obvious built in torch method, or am I stuck with these two options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be this. Simply use broadcasted matrix multiplication over reshaped row vectors of `X` and column vectors of `Y`.

```py
import torch
X = X.reshape(batch_size, 1, d)
Y = Y.reshape(batch_size, d, 1)
product = torch.matmul(X, Y).squeeze(1)
```

The output `product` will have the required shape of `(batch_size, 1)` with the desired result.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you. Trying to visualize what's going on with 3D tensors is always so tricky, but this makes perfect sense.